# How can I properly display a null value of type int in a datagrid to users as a string such as "Not specified"?

Tags: string, silverlight, int, nullable, silverlight-5.0

I have a RadGridView (Telerik) with several columns that represent nullable ints. I have tried using

`TargetNullValue='Not specified'` (in the XAML)

and

`[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Not specified")]` (on the metadata class)

but neither of these have worked. I believe it is likely because I am confusing the string and int data types and the GridView is rejecting it. My users have requested that if an entry is specified for the month (represented as the row in the GridView) but no value is present for the int fields they would like it to be called out in some way. I know I could use the control's conditional color formatting but that is actually being used for something else so it is not an option. Of course whatever is displayed should not be bound to the actual entity value.

Comment: You could write a ValueConverter.

Comment: @jv42 - Could you please put that as an answer? I did not want to have to do it as I thought the property decoration would make it easier, but...

Comment: Once you post it an an answer I'll put the code for my converter on it just in case someone comes searching here.

Comment: You know you can answer your own questions, right?

Comment: @me_and I do, but since jv42 had answered it in a comment I wanted him to get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the usual answer for such cases: write a custom [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that does just that.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    int? num = value as int?;
    if (num != null)
    {
        return num;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Not specified";
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    int num;
    if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out num))
    {
        return num;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know not one jot of whatever language this is, but I'm pretty sure you've a mismatched pair of braces in there somewhere.